# Stylesheet not loaded, even though statics has been configured

Tags: node.js

I'm going crazy over this...

I have this simple NodeJS server running - it serves the ./start.html file fine, but the CSS-file is not loaded.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/public/css/styles.css
/interface.js (the Node-file)
/start.html
```

Node is running this code:

```
const app = express();

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

let serials;

app.use(express.static('public'));
// Make these folders accessible by our HTML-files
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
//app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js')); // Not used at the moment
//app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images')); // Not used at the moment

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
    const fs = require('fs');
    var content;

    // We load the file asynchronously and pass on the content to the screen when loaded.
    fs.readFile('./start.html', function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': data.length, 'Expires': new Date().toUTCString()});
        res.end(data);
    });
});
```

The start.html file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>start</title>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="/text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    etc...
```

When accessed, using **localhost:3000/start**, it only shows the HTML-code.
When opening **localhost:3000/css/styles.css** it displays the stylesheet just fine.
The browser console also does not show any CSS-file loaded.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Replace "app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'))" by app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: Hi Nathan. Sorry, doesn't work - the path isn't located: "Cannot GET /styles.css"

Comment: I just edited my comment, try to replace  "app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'))" by "app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));" and retry with your actual html

Comment: Awww - just found out, why it didn't work. The style sheet call in the HTML is wrong. It should not be  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="/text/css"> but  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">. Sorry for wasting your time, Nathan.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake: the CSS linkage had a "/text/css" instead of "text/css" and not an error in the JS after all. Now it works perfectly.